# Button out of bound using LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I tried to use LinearLayout in order to put 3 Buttons in one row.
The left button (fixed size) should be aligned to left part of screen, right button (fixed size) to the right. Size of middle button should be variable and should fill out rest of space. Result of below stated code is, that the right button is out of bound and not seeable. Can anyone help me solving this issue?

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="1.0">

  <Button
    android:id="@id/LeftButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:elevation="9dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@id/MiddleButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="18dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@id/RightButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the Middle Button width to 0dp this will scale it to fit the missing part.

You can change you layout to:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <Button
    android:id="@id/LeftButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:elevation="9dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@id/MiddleButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="18dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@id/RightButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response, unfortunately middle button is now completely "hidden"...

Comment: Maybe the screen isn't large enough? 
remove the padding from the buttons and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will give you what you need.

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:weightSum="1.0">

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/LeftButton"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:elevation="9dp"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:paddingLeft="10dp"
   android:paddingRight="10dp"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

 <Button
   android:id="@+id/MiddleButton"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingLeft="15dp"
   android:paddingTop="18dp"
   android:layout_weight="0.6"/>

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/RightButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change all of the Buttons width to 0dp when you set layout_weight and LinearLayout on horizontal.

[image]

Comment: When we use linearlayout vertical and set layout_weight Then we should set layout_height = 0dp.

Comment: And When we use linearlayout horizontal and set layout_weight Then we should set layout_height = 0dp.

Comment: Are you asking or telling? 
In vertical case with weight attribute, set `layout_height="0dp"` and in horizontal case with weight attribute, set `layout_width="0dp"`.